# Find the minimizer $u$ of a functional whose derivate contains both $u$ and the sign of $u$

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

> Let $N,h,\gamma,\bar x$ be constants and $x_i\in[-1,1],\forall i=\overline{1,N}$. Consider the following problem
>   $$
>     \min_u J(u^n) \quad\text{subject to}\quad x_i^{n+1} = x_i^n+hu^n
> $$
>   where
>   $$
>    J(u^n) = \frac{1}{2N}\sum_{i=1}^N |x_i^{n+1}-\bar x|^2+h\gamma|u^n|
> $$

Consider the problem on a single time interval $[t^n,t^{n+1}]$ and plug the expression for $x_i^{n+1}$ inside $J$
$$
   J(u^n) = \frac{1}{2N}\sum_i|x_i^n+hu^n-\bar x|^2+h\gamma|u^n|
$$
Derive wrt $u$
\begin{align}
   J'(u^n) &= \frac hN \sum_i (x_i^n+hu^n-\bar x)+h\gamma\,\text{sgn}(u^n) \\
   &= \frac 1N \sum_i(x_i^n-\bar x)+hu^n+\gamma\,\text{sgn}(u^n) = 0
\end{align}
By posing $J'(u)=0$ we should be able to find the $u$ minimizing $J$, but how can we isolate it if we have both $u$ and $\text{sgn}(u)$ appearing?

I'd say that we have to discuss separately the two cases $u$ positive and $u$ negative, but I am a bit confused about how we can find an expression for $u$, in one of the two cases, if we don't know a priori when $u$ is positive or negative.

I mean, in order to know the sign of $u$, we have to compute the formula for $u$, but in order to compute the formula we have to know the sign of $u$, so it seems like we can't do anything.

$u^n>0$
$$
   u^n = \frac {1}{hN} \sum_i(\bar x-x_i^n)-\frac{\gamma}{h}
$$
$u^n<0$
$$
   u^n = \frac {1}{hN} \sum_i(\bar x-x_i^n)+\frac{\gamma}{h}
$$
Since all values on the rhs are known, I think we have to compute both formulas, one of the two will (I hope) contradict the corresponding hypothesis on the sign of $u$, hence the other one will be the correct one.

Comment: This is not correct: $$J'(u^n) = \frac hN \sum_i (x_i^n+hu^n-\bar x)+h\gamma\,\text{sgn}(u^n)$$ $x_i$ is not independent of $u$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Aren't we deriving wrt $u^n$? $x_i$ depends on $u^{n-1}$, right?

Comment: I see a formula relating $x_i$ to $u^n$, not $u^{n-1}$, but even if it were, $u, u^n, u^{n+1}$ are all functions of each other. I wondered if maybe you were using superscripted indices, so $u^n$ would mean the $n^{th}$ coordinate of $u$, but that doesn't make sense, since you said $x_i \in [-1,1]$, so $x_i$ does not have an $n^{th}$ coordinate.

Comment: @PaulSinclair $n$ is the time step, $i$ denotes the coordinate. So the vector $(x_1^n,...,x_N^n)$ describes the system of $N$ particles at time $n$. In your opinion what is the correct expression of $J'(u^n)$?

Comment: So, you didn't bother to give substantial amounts of relevant information with your problem, and part of the information you did give was false (it is each of the $x_i^n \in [-1,1]$, not $x_i$). And even now rather than admit you've been unclear you try to play word games. Fix your question.

Comment: @PaulSinclair https://i.imgur.com/yEY7Z12.png

Comment: @PaulSinclair see here for all the information https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591793/find-minimizer-of-cost-function-in-model-predictive-control-mpc